# Sed command to uppercase text between two specific strings

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I want to parse a file and replace the text between "::" and ":::" with the text already there, just now capitalized.

I've tried using this command:

`sed 's/\(::\)\(.*\)\(:::\)/\1\U\2\E\3/' filename`

but the output just puts a U in beginning and E at the end of the string I want capitalized

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does one confuse Linux and OS X? Apple hardware is exclusively for OS X. It is not like you have a MacBook Pro running Linux...

Comment: again, haven't been doing this for very long. my understanding was OS X was built from linux and therefore had compatibility.

Comment: Close, macOS was built from UNIX, not Linux. There is a difference between the two and how commands are interpreted, as tink's answer explains.

Comment: `edit` your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Include cases where your start/end strings occur multiple times on one line and any other unusual; cases you can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, which makes me think you may not be on Linux?

```
echo "This is :: some sample text ::: to test uppercasing" | sed 's/\(::\)\(.*\)\(:::\)/\1\U\2\E\3/' 
This is :: SOME SAMPLE TEXT ::: to test uppercasing
```

Comment: you're right, I'm on Mac. Still new to this and thought they were essentially the same.

Comment: No, far from it. they have many commands by the same name, but the BSD variants are **more true** to old POSIX norms, which also means that they don't support many of the extended features.  If you want a linux like `sed`, `awk`, `grep` experience install homebrew and get the GNU equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

If `Perl` is your option, you can say something like:

```
echo "This is :: some sample text ::: to test uppercasing" | perl -pe 's/(::)(.*)(:::)/\1\U\2\E\3/'
This is :: SOME SAMPLE TEXT ::: to test uppercasing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '{match($0,/::.*:::/,a) ;gsub(/::.*::/,toupper(a[0]))}1' input
```

Here ,bit less cryptic solution with `gawk`:, `match` is used to find the desired string ,later that string is used by `gsub` to convert it to upped cause using `toupper` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.

On Mac OS X, you will need to install GNU sed, because the feature you are using - `\U` - is a GNU extension.

So, start by installing it:

```
▶ brew install gnu-sed
```

Then I normally stick in some code like this somewhere:

```bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias sed='/usr/local/bin/gsed'
```

And then your GNU sed will work.

Finally, I would simplify that code as:

```
▶ sed -E 's/(::)(.*)(::)/\1\U\2\E\3/' <<< "foo::bar::baz" 
foo::BAR::baz
```

Noting that `-E` gives you Extended Regular Expressions, and a cleaner syntax when you are doing captures.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/::[^:]*:::/\U&/' file
```

or perhaps:

```
sed 's/::[^:]*:::/\n&\n/;h;y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/;G;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*\n\(.*\)\n.*\n/\2\1/' file
```

Using seds  `y` native translate command, pattern matching and a copy held in the hold space.